# How to change url of Proceed to Checkout

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout, url, url-rewrite

I would like to manually rewrite to `mydomain.com/index.php/customer/account/login`
Instead of `mydomain.com/customer/account/login`. As am facing issues due to url rewrite.

Comment: Can you also tell us what issues you are facing due to the rewrite?  Perhaps we can address those issues instead of having you disable rewriting.

Comment: I am getting page not found error due to this url

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this result by changing *System > Configuration > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization* field *Use Web Server Rewrites* to *No*

Comment: Its value is no only.